# Authorized.net Gateway error: This account has not been given the permissions(s) required for this request

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm getting this gateway error `Gateway error: This account has not been given the permissions(s) required for this request` while trying to checkout. Before this, i successfully have tested with sandbox account. And after i setup all with valid merchant credentials it's showing me this popup.

And via debug i got this as a result

```
    [result] => Array
    (
        [response_code] => 3
        [response_subcode] => 3
        [response_reason_code] => 123
        [response_reason_text] => This account has not been given the permission(s) required for this request.
        [approval_code] => 
        [avs_result_code] => P
        [transaction_id] => 0
        [invoice_number] => 
        [description] => 
        [amount] => 0.02
        [method] => 
        [transaction_type] => auth_capture
        [customer_id] => 
        [md5_hash] => 48D5E8D8EA7331B74B9C486F9BFE5811
        [card_code_response_code] => 
        [c_av_vresponse_code] => 
        [split_tender_id] => 
        [acc_number] => 
        [card_type] => 
        [requested_amount] => 
        [balance_on_card] => 
    )
```

I am testing this in draftserver/staging site where there is no ssl or something as security. is that being the cause for this. Below is the screenshot of error
[image]

Comment: There are some suggestions in the response code lookup tool: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=123

Comment: @rhldr thanks, it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the response code lookup to find suggestions: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=123